# python spyder editor change menu and font size

Tags: python, spyder

I have shared displays and the menu font size (e.g. File Edit Search ..) but also the font of the names of python files above the editor window, are really small, making it hard to read.

I looked in "Preferences" and elsewhere, but I don't find any option to modify the font size of menu and filenames (while it is easy to modify the editor python code font size).

I attach a screenshot for illustration.

Thanks for your help.
[screenshot of the Spyder window: the menu font size is really small, while the editing Python font size can be increased](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNWUY.png)

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) If I'm not wrong, the size of your font size in menus is controlled by your operating system (Windows, Linux, macOS), so you need to look for options to do that in your respective OS. The only thing we provide in Spyder akin to that is located in `Preferences > General > Screen resolution`, which let's you increase/decrease the screen resolution, but only for Spyder.

Answer (score 3):

If your computer has a high-resolution screen, the menu in the interface is rather small.

This can be corrected by activating scaling for high-resolution screens in

tools/preferences/application/interface/.

Comment: This worked for me on a macbook pro.

Answer (score 1):

Go to tools/preferences/application/interface/ and setup a high DPI scaling of 1